# What will happen when we create an object outside the method?

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a question related to OOP.

what is the effect, if we make an object outside the method.

*Is that object becomes global?*

Here is some code..

```
class A(){
 String b;
 public void c(){
  //some code in here}
 }

 class C(){

 A a = new A(); //is this ok and if it is ok what is this mean??

 public void p(){
 a.c(); //Is this possible??
}
}
```

Comment: objects can only be instanciated in methods. So it is not possible in the first place.

Comment: If it's static, it will be global. Otherwise it would be an instance member, available to all the non-static methods of the class (and possibly to other classes, depending on its access modifier).

Comment: You can't create an object outside of any method.  And objects aren't local, global, instance scope of any of that -- only their *references* have such attributes.

Comment: yes. the variable is 'global' if it is declared inside a class but outside any method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are very new to Java or Object Oriented Programming.

There are two steps to create an object in Java: **Declaration** and **initialization**

**Declaration** means you are declaring that something exists.
Eg: `String title;` means, there exists a string object named title.
**Initialization** is assigning value to it. ie: `title = "Hello World!";`. But before initializing an object you need to make sure it is declared. Also you can combine declaration and initialization in one statement: `String title = "Hello World!";`

The **scope** of the object *depends up on* where you declare that object.
If you declare it inside a class like this:

```
class Car {
  String name; //These are called fields
  static String author = "Farseen"
  public void doSomething() {..../*can access name and author*/}
  public static void doSomething() {..../*can access author only*/}
}
```

everything inside the class will have access to it, except the static (we'll get to that in a while) methods.These are called **fields**
If you decalare it inside a method, only that method will have access to it:

```
class Car {
  public void doSomething() {
    String name = "BMW"; //These are called local variables
  }
  public void doSomeOtherThing() {
    //Cannot acccess name
  }
}
```

These are called **local variables**

If you declare it outside a class, sorry Java does not allow you to do that. Everything must be inside a class.

You can prefix declarations outside methods, that are fields with access modifiers:

**public** : Makes the field accessible to anyone. It is legal to :
`Car myCar = new Car();System.out.println(myCar.name);`

**private** : Makes the field accessible to the methods(functions) inside the class only. It is *illegal* to :
`Car myCar = new Car();System.out.println(myCar.name);`

**protected** : Makes the field accessible to the subclasses of that class. It is also not accessible to users, like private.

Now comes in the **static** modifier:

It says that the field or method(function) belongs to the *entire species* of car, instead of individual cars.
It is legal to access the static field `author` like this: `Car.author` no need to create an individual car, although it is legal : `new Car().author`
The static things only know about static things, not individual things.

There is **no concept** of **Global Variables** in Java. Although, you can achieve it using some thing like this:

```
class Globals {
    public static String GLOBAL_VARIABLE_MESSAGE = "Hello World!";
}
```

And use it somewhere in your code using `Globals.GLOBAL_VARIABLE_MESSAGE`

Hope it helps!

**Edit: referring to the code added to the question**

```
class A{ //Parenthesis are NOT needed
         // or allowed in class definition:
         // 'class A()' is wrong
 String b;
 public void c(){
  //some code in here
 }
}

 class C{ //Same here. No parenthesis needed
  A a = new A(); //Q: Is this ok and if it is ok what is this mean??
                 //A: Yes, completely ok.
                 // This means you added
                 // a field 'a' of type A to the class C

 public void p(){
  a.c(); //Q: Is this possible??
         //A: Of course
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made some edits to your code and added answers to your doubts

```
class A{ 
 String b;
 public void c(){
  //some code in here}
 }

 class C{

 A a = new A(); //is this ok and if it is ok what is this mean??--It is Ok.it means that a is instance variable of type A.

 public void p(){
 a.c(); //Is this possible?? -- It is possible. since c() is a method in class A.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you create an object has little to do with it being "global". It is all about the scope of accessibily of a *reference* to that object. To give two extreme opposites, both involving instantiation outside of a method:

```
public static final File f = new File(new File("/x/a"), "b");
```

The above line will cause two instances of `File` to be created: one will become global, the other will be completely inaccessible and disposed of on the spot.

Comment: Actually, that's not outside of a method.  The code is executed in the static init method (`<clinit>`).

Comment: OK, *technically*. But I don't think that's what OP meant by "method".